# Quartz Schedular not reflecting Code Changes

Tags: java, batch-file, quartz-scheduler

I'm building a small application of Employee Management System,in my application I have a quartz Scheduler it used for tracking daily employee attendance,leave info etc.This batch is scheduled to be run every day at 11pm.

Now,I have made some changes in my java code for leave calculation,this code is supposed to be run under batch.Its working fine in my local environment as well as in DEV environment,but after releasing it to PROD the newly made code changes is not getting reflected when the batch runs.There are no error messages in log as well as The scheduler is also firing at 11pm but newly made code changes are not getting reflected in PROD.

One thing I would like to mention is that my local Scheduler as well as DEV scheduler are started and stopped manually by the user through a GUI.But the prod scheduler remains started throughout the entire year for everyday record tracking.

Can anyone give any feasible solution to this??????remember I'm getting this problem only in PROD server

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure your scheduler is destroyed when you undeploy the application. It's probably still firing for code from the previous version, because it created its own thread which doesn't get stopped.

If this is too hard, just restart the PROD server.

You might also want to look into Java EE scheduled tasks instead of Quartz: http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/bnboy.html

Comment: well I'm explaining you the process of our deployment.As I have said our prod batch remains on throughout the year,so we are not stopping the batch.we are just stopping the prod server and replacing the existing project war file with latest(updated) war file and then stating the server again.

Comment: It would help if you could update the question with more details on how you're using and configuring Quartz

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have undeployed it cleanly and deploy it again.
Probably your old code still exist in staging area of PROD server